# Create a tree from a list of strings - javascript

Tags: javascript, tree, treeview

I have an array of objects and I want to create a view tree. But I have a problem with creating. My name Test1/Test2 and Test1/Test2/Test3 (id 147) was missed in final tree.

My snippet:

```js
let arr = [{id: 145, name: "Test1/Test2", public: false},
{id: 146, name: "Test1/Test2/Test3", public: false},
{id: 147, name: "Test1/Test2/Test3", public: false},
{id: 148, name: "Test1/Test2/Test4", public: false}];
let result = [];
let level = { result };

arr.forEach((path) => {
  path.name.split("/").reduce((r, name, i, a) => {
    if (!r[name]) {
      r[name] = { result: [], id: path.id };
      r.result.push({ name, children: r[name].result });
     }
     return r[name];
    }, level);
});

console.log(result)
```

Expected result:

```
[
      {
        name: "Test1",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Test2",
            children: [],
            id: 145
          },
          {
            name: "Test2",
            children: [
              {
                name: "Test3",
                children: [],
                id: 146
              },
              {
                name: "Test3",
                children: [],
                id: 147
              },
              {
                name: "Test4",
                children: [],
                id: 148
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
```

Comment: please add the wanted result. what should happen to multiple `id`?

Comment: @NinaScholz Hello. added

Comment: what if you have `'Test1/Test2/Test3/Test5'` as well. where should it go?

Comment: @NinaScholz I think, it will be added to Test1/Test2 as a 4 element Test3 with child Test5

Comment: why do you have not multiple `Test1`?

Comment: Because Test1 is root

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223458/discussion-between-user233428-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, the number of leaves in your tree should equal the number entries in the input array. So a leaf would never get any children. This is what made you give "Test1" two children, even though all paths have "Test2" as the next part: one child for a leaf, and another functioning as internal node.

By consequence, leaves don't really need a `children` property, as that `children` array would always remain empty.

It is clear that the last element of a path needs to be processed a bit differently. That part should always result in the creation of a new node in the tree. The other parts can reuse a (non-leaf) node, if one is available.

This leads to the following change in your code:

```js
let arr = [
    {id: 145, name: "Test1/Test2", public: false},
    {id: 146, name: "Test1/Test2/Test3", public: false},
    {id: 147, name: "Test1/Test2/Test3", public: false},
    {id: 148, name: "Test1/Test2/Test4", public: false}
];
let result = [];
let level = { result };

arr.forEach(({name, id}) => { // destructure
  let parts = name.split("/");
  name = parts.pop(); // don't pass the last part through reducer
  parts.reduce((r, name, i) => {
    if (!r[name]) {
      r[name] = { result: [] };
      r.result.push({ name, children: r[name].result });
     }
     return r[name];
  }, level).result.push({ name, id }); // add last part here
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!